# Date formatting in table in angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material, date-formatting

Hi I'm making a table for following up projects. At the moment I only need dumy fata in it but I cannot make date formatting to work. I would like to display the dates in yyyy.mm.dd. format eg. 2023.04.03. I tried to use Date Pipe but cannot make it work somehow :( What do I miss?

This is my code now:

```
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, of as observableOf, merge } from 'rxjs';

export interface MunkatablaItem {
  Client: string;
  id: string;
  Projekt: string;
  Felelos: string;
  Statusz: string;
  Ertek: string;
  Hatarido: Date;
  Kozremukodo: string;
  Megjegyzes: string;
}

const EXAMPLE_DATA: MunkatablaItem[] = [
  {id: '23-0001', Client: 'Hydrogen', Projekt: 'Zónabesorolás', Felelos: 'Teszt Elek', Statusz: 'Folyamatban', Ertek: '6200000', Hatarido: new Date('2023-04-23'), Kozremukodo: 'Kolléga', Megjegyzes: 'PO: ZB-234567' },
  {id: '23-0002', Client: 'Helium', Projekt: 'Felülvizsgálat', Felelos: 'Teszt Elek', Statusz: 'Folyamatban', Ertek: '6200000', Hatarido: new Date ('2023-04-01'), Kozremukodo: 'Kolléga', Megjegyzes: 'PO: ZB-234567' },
  {id: '23-0003', Client: 'Lithium', Projekt: 'Szoftverfejlesztés', Felelos: 'Teszt Elek', Statusz: 'Folyamatban', Ertek: '6200000', Hatarido: new Date('2023-04-23'), Kozremukodo: 'Kolléga', Megjegyzes: 'PO: ZB-234567' },
  {id: '23-0004', Client: 'Beryllium', Projekt: 'Felülvizsgálat', Felelos: 'Teszt Elek', Statusz: 'Folyamatban', Ertek: '6200000', Hatarido: new Date('2023-04-23'), Kozremukodo: 'Kolléga', Megjegyzes: 'PO: ZB-234567' },
  {id: '23-0005', Client: 'Boron', Projekt: 'Felülvizsgálat', Felelos: 'Teszt Elek', Statusz: 'Folyamatban', Ertek: '6200000', Hatarido: new Date('2023-04-23'), Kozremukodo: 'Kolléga', Megjegyzes: 'PO: ZB-234567' },
  {id: '23-0006', Client: 'Carbon', Projekt: 'Felülvizsgálat', Felelos: 'Teszt Elek', Statusz: 'Folyamatban', Ertek: '6200000', Hatarido: new Date('2023-04-23'), Kozremukodo: 'Kolléga', Megjegyzes: 'PO: ZB-234567' },
  {id: '23-0007', Client: 'Nitrogen', Projekt: 'Felülvizsgálat', Felelos: 'Teszt Elek', Statusz: 'Folyamatban', Ertek: '6200000', Hatarido: new Date('2023-04-23'), Kozremukodo: 'Kolléga', Megjegyzes: 'PO: ZB-234567' },
  {id: '23-0008', Client: 'Oxygen', Projekt: 'Felülvizsgálat', Felelos: 'Teszt Elek', Statusz: 'Folyamatban', Ertek: '6200000', Hatarido: new Date('2023-04-23'), Kozremukodo: 'Kolléga', Megjegyzes: 'PO: ZB-234567' },
  {id: '23-0009', Client: 'Fluorine', Projekt: 'Felülvizsgálat', Felelos: 'Teszt Elek', Statusz: 'Folyamatban', Ertek: '6200000', Hatarido: new Date('2023-04-23'), Kozremukodo: 'Kolléga', Megjegyzes: 'PO: ZB-234567' },
  {id: '23-0010', Client: 'Neon', Projekt: 'Felülvizsgálat', Felelos: 'Teszt Elek', Statusz: 'Folyamatban', Ertek: '6200000', Hatarido: new Date('2023-04-23'), Kozremukodo: 'Kolléga', Megjegyzes: 'PO: ZB-234567' },
  {id: '23-0011', Client: 'Sodium', Projekt: 'Felülvizsgálat', Felelos: 'Teszt Elek', Statusz: 'Folyamatban', Ertek: '6200000', Hatarido: new Date('2023-04-23'), Kozremukodo: 'Kolléga', Megjegyzes: 'PO: ZB-234567' },
  {id: '23-0012', Client: 'Magnesium', Projekt: 'Felülvizsgálat', Felelos: 'Teszt Elek', Statusz: 'Folyamatban', Ertek: '6200000', Hatarido: new Date('2023-04-23'), Kozremukodo: 'Kolléga', Megjegyzes: 'PO: ZB-234567' },
  {id: '23-0013', Client: 'Aluminum', Projekt: 'Felülvizsgálat', Felelos: 'Teszt Elek', Statusz: 'Folyamatban', Ertek: '6200000', Hatarido: new Date('2023-04-23'), Kozremukodo: 'Kolléga', Megjegyzes: 'PO: ZB-234567' },
  {id: '23-0014', Client: 'Silicon', Projekt: 'Felülvizsgálat', Felelos: 'Teszt Elek', Statusz: 'Folyamatban', Ertek: '6200000', Hatarido: new Date('2023-04-23'), Kozremukodo: 'Kolléga', Megjegyzes: 'PO: ZB-234567' },
  {id: '23-0015', Client: 'Phosphorus', Projekt: 'Felülvizsgálat', Felelos: 'Teszt Elek', Statusz: 'Folyamatban', Ertek: '6200000', Hatarido: new Date('2023-04-23'), Kozremukodo: 'Kolléga', Megjegyzes: 'PO: ZB-234567' },
];

/**
 * Data source for the Munkatabla view. This class should
 * encapsulate all logic for fetching and manipulating the displayed data
 * (including sorting, pagination, and filtering).
 */
export class MunkatablaDataSource extends DataSource<MunkatablaItem> {
  data: MunkatablaItem[] = EXAMPLE_DATA;
  paginator: MatPaginator | undefined;
  sort: MatSort | undefined;

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  /**
   * Connect this data source to the table. The table will only update when
   * the returned stream emits new items.
   * @returns A stream of the items to be rendered.
   */
  connect(): Observable<MunkatablaItem[]> {
    if (this.paginator && this.sort) {
      // Combine everything that affects the rendered data into one update
      // stream for the data-table to consume.
      return merge(observableOf(this.data), this.paginator.page, this.sort.sortChange)
        .pipe(map(() => {
          return this.getPagedData(this.getSortedData([...this.data ]));
        }));
    } else {
      throw Error('Please set the paginator and sort on the data source before connecting.');
    }
  }

  /**
   *  Called when the table is being destroyed. Use this function, to clean up
   * any open connections or free any held resources that were set up during connect.
   */
  disconnect(): void {}

  /**
   * Paginate the data (Client-side). If you're using server-side pagination,
   * this would be replaced by requesting the appropriate data from the server.
   */
  private getPagedData(data: MunkatablaItem[]): MunkatablaItem[] {
    if (this.paginator) {
      const startIndex = this.paginator.pageIndex * this.paginator.pageSize;
      return data.splice(startIndex, this.paginator.pageSize);
    } else {
      return data;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Sort the data (Client-side). If you're using server-side sorting,
   * this would be replaced by requesting the appropriate data from the server.
   */
  private getSortedData(data: MunkatablaItem[]): MunkatablaItem[] {
    if (!this.sort || !this.sort.active || this.sort.direction === '') {
      return data;
    }

    return data.sort((a, b) => {
      const isAsc = this.sort?.direction === 'asc';
      switch (this.sort?.active) {
        case 'Client': return compare(a.Client, b.Client, isAsc);
        case 'id': return compare(+a.id, +b.id, isAsc);
        default: return 0;
      }
    });
  }
}

/** Simple sort comparator for example ID/Client columns (for Client-side sorting). */
function compare(a: string | number, b: string | number, isAsc: boolean): number {
  return (a < b ? -1 : 1) * (isAsc ? 1 : -1);
}
```

Comment: can you share your code on stackblitz

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7g8pfw?file=src/app/navbar/navbar.component.spec.ts